# PHP music play/pause button

Tags: javascript, php

**Hi**,
i am working on a project where i have a music button which is used to start/play and stop/pause the background music. 
**PROBLEM:**
Problem is that i have many pages in my website when i press the music stop/pause button the music stops playing but when i navigate to different pages the music starts automatically and i again need to press the button on every new page loaded to stop the music playing on background.**Solution Needed** i want solution that if i press the music stop button the music must stop for the whole website until i again press the button to play the music.

```js
<audio id="audio" autoplay="" src="music/music.mp3" loop="true"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">

var sounds = document.getElementById('audio');


  document.getElementById('myAudio').onclick= function(){
    var sounds = document.getElementById('audio');
    if(sounds.paused){
     
      sounds.play();
    }else{

      sounds.pause();

    }
  }
```

```html
<a><img id="myAudio" src="images/musicicob.png"></a>
 <?php include'audio.php'; ?>
```

Comment: use localStorage

Comment: Autoplaying music on websites is a UX nightmare. Make sure that this actually provides value to you visitors and does not make them leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **localStorage**

1) when user click pause button set the item **localStorage.setItem('music','stop');** an each page load check the localstorage and pause audio like this.

```
var sounds = document.getElementById('audio');
if(localstorage.getItem('music')=='stop'){

  sounds.pause();
}else{

  sounds.play();
}
```

2) when user click play button set the item **localStorage.setItem('music','play');**

Answer (score 1):

use localStorage OR maybe the **sessionStrage** to have a reset of the setting when closing the browser!?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage